# how to use performSegueWithIdentifier in apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch

I always used the feature `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"changeView" sender:self];`

someone can say how this works for apple watch?

Answer (score 1):

[WKInterfaceController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014957-CH1-SW27) shows you how to use segues with identifiers
(contextForSegueWithIdentifier:) but i think the best use is "presentControllerWithName:context:" and "pushControllerWithName:context:", you can assign a name for the View from the Interface Builder; when you try to create a segue from the controller to the desire view, normally it creates a page, you need to create a button for that action, using the methods i've told you before, you don't need to create the segues on IB, just identify the views and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a table, you can use `table.performSegue(forRow: 0)` in watchOS 3. Otherwise, you have to use `pushControllerWithName:context:` or `presentControllerWithName:context:`.